# Flash AS 2 Button

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I recently made a website, and the buttons look like this:

On(release)
{
gotoAndPlay ("title", 1);
}

My problem is, when you click the button the first time, it goes to the correct frame. but when you click it again, it goes to the next frame, or to the next scene. How do I remedy this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The args for gotoAndPlay are scene and frame. So without seeing your code I can only recommend that you

- have more than one scene
- have a scene named "title"
- if you have a scene named "title" that it has more than a couple of frames in it, as well as something that will "stop" the timeline

Comment: I have more than one scene. Here are the codes. 
for the home button its like this:

on(release)
{
 gotoAndPlay ("Home",84);
 
}

for the about us button it is like this:
on(release)
{
 gotoAndPlay ("about us",84);
 
}

for the contact us button its like this:

on(release)
{
 gotoAndPlay ("contact us",84);
 
}

Actually, these buttons work perfectly. even if I change scenes, those buttons still work. I guess because they are different scenes. But when I have buttons on different frames, those are the ones that go to different frames when i click the button a second time.